# Как отсортировать массив объектов по строковому значению?

Tags: javascript

Люди добрые, помогите понять как сортируются подобные массивы, нужно отсортировать по строковому значению `price`. Нужно 2 массива, с сортировкой убыванию и по возростанию.

Пробовал при помощи `sort` с использованием `localeCompare`, но это не срабатывает

```js
let arrObj = [
  { key: 'hguh93', price: '584' },
  { key: 'h7d4hk', price: '654' },
  { key: 'lo5zi9', price: '84.5' },
  { key: '0hs3kl', price: '4.58' },
  { key: '6hjfwe', price: '984.1' },
  { key: '824rds', price: '0.45' },
];

arrObj.sort((x, y) => x.price.localeCompare(y.price));

console.log( 'Сортировка по убыванию:' );
console.log( arrObj );
console.log( 'Сортировка по возростанию:' );
console.log( arrObj );
```

Comment: Цены нужно сортировать как текст или как числа?

Comment: Наверное как числа в процессе сортировки, главное чтобы на выводе были в строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблемы, а) массив сортировался всегда по возрастанию, б) не было двух массивов, отсортированных по-разному. Первая проблема решается применением множителя `-1` к результату метода `localeCompare` (который возвращает -1, 0 или 1), вторая - созданием копий массива.

**Сортировка цен как чисел:**

```js
let arrObj = [
    {key: 'hguh93', price: '584'},
    {key: 'h7d4hk', price: '654'},
    {key: 'lo5zi9', price: '84.5'},
    {key: '0hs3kl', price: '4.58'},
    {key: '6hjfwe', price: '984.1'},
    {key: '824rds', price: '0.45'},
];

down = arrObj.slice()
down.sort((x, y) => parseFloat(y.price) - parseFloat(x.price));
up = arrObj.slice()
up.sort((x, y) => parseFloat(x.price) - parseFloat(y.price));

console.log('Сортировка по убыванию:');
console.log(down);

console.log('Сортировка по возрастанию:');
console.log(up);
```

**Сортировка цен как текста:**

```js
let arrObj = [
    {key: 'hguh93', price: '584'},
    {key: 'h7d4hk', price: '654'},
    {key: 'lo5zi9', price: '84.5'},
    {key: '0hs3kl', price: '4.58'},
    {key: '6hjfwe', price: '984.1'},
    {key: '824rds', price: '0.45'},
];

down = arrObj.slice() // копируем массив
down.sort((x, y) => -1 * x.price.localeCompare(y.price)); // меняем порядок сортировки умножением на -1
up = arrObj.slice() // копируем массив
up.sort((x, y) => x.price.localeCompare(y.price));

console.log('Сортировка по убыванию:');
console.log(down);

console.log('Сортировка по возрастанию:');
console.log(up);
```

Comment: Кстати обратную сортировку можно так сделать `arrObj.reverse();`, хак придумал)) Главное только один раз отсортировать в какую то сторону